# jquery mouseout of nested div question

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to fire a function on the mouseout of a div.  However when you mousover an element in the div it fires the mouseout.

```
<div id="my_div">
    <div class="another_div">X</div>
</div>

<script>
$("#my_div").mouseout(function () {
    alert('weeeee, I am out!');
}
</script>
```

This makes sense but how can I test for the mouseout event only if it is not on a child element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the [MouseLeave](http://docs.jquery.it/Events/mouseleave) event rather than the mouseout, according to the API:

> Mouseout fires when the pointer moves
>   into or out from child element, while
>   mouseleave doesn't.

Comment: Same result as with mouseout.

Comment: @ws0x9, it should work  .. you are doing something wrong ..

your example with mouseleave : http://jsbin.com/emelu/2 works

Answer (score 3):

you want this:

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/mouseenter and http://docs.jquery.com/Events/mouseleave